# GlobalChannelInterceptor pass array of patterns

Tags: spring-integration

I am Spring Integration 4.3.13 and trying to pass patterns when configuring @GlobalChannelInterceptor

Here is the example

```
@Configuration
public class IntegrationConfig{

   @Bean
   @GlobalChannelInterceptor(patterns = "${spring.channel.interceptor.patterns:*}")

 public ChannelInterceptor channelInterceptor(){
    return new ChannelInterceptorImpl();
 }

}
```

properties file has following values:

spring.channel.interceptor.patterns=*intchannel, *event

I am using direct channels with names that end with these two string

1. springintchannel
2. registrationevent

With the above config, both the channels should have interceptor configured but it is not getting configured.

Answer (score 1):

The comma-separate value isn't support there currently.

I agree that we need to fix it, so feel free to raise a JIRA on the matter and we will file a solution from some other place.

Meanwhile you can do this as a workaround:

```
    @Bean
    public GlobalChannelInterceptorWrapper channelInterceptorWrapper(@Value("${spring.channel.interceptor.patterns:*}") String[] patterns) {
        GlobalChannelInterceptorWrapper globalChannelInterceptorWrapper = new GlobalChannelInterceptorWrapper(channelInterceptor());
        globalChannelInterceptorWrapper.setPatterns(patterns);
        return globalChannelInterceptorWrapper;
    }
```